# Create form with many-to-many data with add driver button

Tags: php, html, forms, many-to-many, one-to-many

I want to create a form that allows me to enter the related data for example, I have a table Company and another table with Drivers, so what I want is in one form enter all the info of the company and then the form allows me to enter the driver data with for example add driver button or something like that???

any ideas??/

Comment: Your question is very general. I'm guessing you're trying to save the data into a Database? Is there a specific issue we can help with?

Comment: You can create a form on company page. With form submit, insert all data into database and then redirect to driver page, with another form for driver DB.

Comment: I will try my best now to explain what I want in a much better way with another case , I have seen in many pages that when I'm typing my contact info that forms allows me to add many phone numbers in several input fields that I can see when i click in to a button , my guess is that they have a one to many relation between contact and phone numbers , that is what i want.